# Health inspector

Tags: word-usage, professions

Is there a term for the person who goes to restaurants and checks if anything is wrong?

This person does not introduce himself at first. He eats food and sees the restaurant, and if the restaurant is dirty or the food is not good, he can report this problem and ask the health department to close the restaurant because it has low standards.

Can *health inspector* be used?

Comment: A health inspector may do this, or, to a degree, a private citizen can do it.  It's generally unlikely that a heath inspector will do this since if he did it much his picture would be posted on the wall in the kitchen.

Comment: So in your opinion, just people report problems to Health Department. Am I right?

Comment: In theory, in the US, health departments do inspections of restaurants from time to time.  These are not "secret", but they may be unannounced.  Someone posing as a private citizen, even if actually a bona fide inspector, would not be able to inspect many areas of the kitchen.  As to whether private citizens often report problems, that's hard to say.

Comment: I'd be surprised if government-funded inspectors in the UK often (if ever) visit premises *incognito*. They go to great lengths to work *with* the management/staff to resolve problems, most of which they couldn't even identify unless they check out the entire premises. So they need free access to kitchens, storage facilities, etc.

Comment: But the employee of the health department who does the inspections is commonly referred to as a "health inspector", though individual agencies may have their own internal bureaucratic terms.

Comment: On [the relevant pages](http://www.food.gov.uk/business-industry/hygieneratings/food-law-inspections#toc-2) this gov.UK site only ever calls them "inspectors" (I'd say they're a specialised subset of "Health & Safety Inspectors").

Answer (score 1):

**mystery consumer** (or ***costumer***) is what they are called, and **mystery shopping** is the name of their practice.

> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mystery_shopping)